# Error JSON com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 middle

Tags: android, json, rest, utf

I'm developing an application in Android where I can insert new comments (like in facebook or any other social network).

The function that does it is the following :

```
public static String putNewComment(String comment, int userId, int trackId) throws IOException,JSONException {

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Globals.PUBLISH_NEW_COMMENT);

    StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"comment\": \""+comment+"\",\"trackId\":"+trackId+",\"userId\":"+userId+"}");
    input.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    post.setEntity(input);
    input.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setEntity(input);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post,Globals.localContext);
    System.out.println("Response Code : "
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String resultMy="";
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        resultMy+=line;
        System.out.println("Server says: "+line);
    }

    return resultMy;

}
```

Every time I try to put a new comment that contains unicode characters like é,ò, and several others I get this error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22

Now, I am aware of the fact that the error is due to the fact that the content encoding is UTF-8 and I'm trying to insert an unicode character. 
The problem is how to fix this? I tried by changing in this way :

```
input.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-16");
    post.setEntity(input);
    input.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-16"));
```

or

```
input.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-32");
    post.setEntity(input);
    input.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-32"));
```

But it doesn't work !
Please help me

Comment: `StringEntity`, read the doc for that.

Comment: I can't understand what you are referring to ..

Comment: for starters, where exactly do you get this error? it's out of context, and there is no reference to jackson in your code